# Blocking until logmessage with Spotify Docker Java Client

Tags: java, docker, jenkins

### Description

Im using the following function to be able to block surefire tests until the docker container is started.
This works almost always but some of the time im getting the exception shown below. Im unsure under what situations `next` would fail for a `LogStream` or if there is an issue with how `dockerClient.logs` gets the log stream.

> My questions are:
>
> How are others using the docker client to wait for
>   logs?
>
> What would cause the exceptions im seeing?

```
public void waitForLog(String messageToMatch) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Waiting for toc.log to signal start of service with log message: " + messageToMatch);
    LogStream logs = dockerClient.logs(container.id(), follow(), stdout());
    String log;
    do {
        LogMessage logMessage = logs.next();
        ByteBuffer buffer = logMessage.content();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
        buffer.get(bytes);
        log = new String(bytes);
    } while (!log.contains(messageToMatch));
}
```

### How to reproduce

Im still not sure how to reproduce since it only happens rarely on my local machine but always on our Jenkins servers.

### What do you expect

No exeption thrown, we will read the logs.

### What happened instead

Exception is thrown.

### Software:

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:01:32 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.0-ce
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   3a232c8
 Built:        Tue Feb 28 08:01:32 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Spotify's docker-client version: `7.0.2`

### Full backtrace

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
    at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.next(AbstractIterator.java:154)
    at com.support.test.core.docker.DockerProxy.waitForLog(DockerProxy.java:175)
    at com.support.test.core.runner.TestListener.testRunStarted(TestListener.java:54)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.SynchronizedRunListener.testRunStarted(SynchronizedRunListener.java:35)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$1.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:91)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestRunStarted(RunNotifier.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```